# Iphone app - Cocos2D - create/display second view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I need help as I am stuck in my Iphone app project – I am trying to understand what I have to add to my code (and where) in order to create a second view (to show app options or to draw a chart) and to display it. All the tutorials I have seen refer to the interface designer whereas I would like to do that programmatically (I use the cocos2D library). This may sound like a “déjà vu” question but I could not find a clear explanation, I am pretty sure that this would help a lot of people.
Any tip would be welcome!
Many thanks guys
M.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppController *app =  (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
 [app.navController.view addSubview:newView];
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends if you want to add a subview to the currently existing root controller or reestablish a new view controller.

You may need to add the header of the view you want to add to the implementation file you're trying to do this in.

Here is the code to do the reestablish new view controller way:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
...

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIViewController *mvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil]; //Allocate the View Controller

window.rootViewController = mvc;   //Set the view controller
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

the other way:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
...

UIViewController *new = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview: new.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a second view of cocos2d, then the answer is simple: you can't.

It's a planned feature to allow multiple cocos2d views but thus far it hasn't been implemented.